# Custom filter using Angular

Tags: angular, sorting, filtering, asp.net-mvc-custom-filter

I have a list of text fields that needs a custom filter.

Suppose when the user searches with a specific string/character, the app has to show only that records in the table view.

Comment: Can you please show some efforts that you have tried so far...! :)

Comment: So search should be performed locally? i.e all of your table data is loaded in one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here list which is in the grid**
[image: Here is the list which is in the grid]

**After using the pipe (custom filter)**
[image: After using the pipe (custom filter)]

This can be achieved by using custom filter in angular , first we have create a pipe using (ng g pipe filterName), navigate to pipe component which u generate and make use of transform method, here is the transform method i used

```
transform(items: any, a: string, b: string, c: string){
if (items && items.length){
    return items.filter(item =>{
        if (a&& item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(a.toLowerCase()) === -1){
            return false;
        }
        if (b && item.industry.toLowerCase().indexOf(b.toLowerCase()) === -1){
            return false;
        }
        if (c&& item.location.toLowerCase().indexOf(c.toLowerCase()) === -1){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
   })
}
else{
    return items;
}
```

}
then navigate to particular html where u gonna use custom filter

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="a">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="b">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="c">
<div *ngFor="let item of data | customFilter :a:b:c">
  {{item.{{item.city}}}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write an Angular pipe (https://angular.io/guide/pipes) to transform your list.

Example:

`ng generate pipe filter`

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterPipe'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(textFields: string[], searchWord: string): any {
    return textFields.filter(val => val.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord));
  }

}
```

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let field of textFields | filterPipe : searchWord"></li>
</ul>
```